# Why is element not being shown before alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In this simple example https://jsfiddle.net/4rsje4b6/1/ why is the `#test` element not being shown before the alert appears?

Shouldn't the jQuery `css()` method be syncronous?

```
#test {
  display: none;
}
```

```
<span id="test">Element</span>
```

```
$("#test").css("display", "inline");
alert("Showed element!");
```

**UPDATE:**

This behavior is manifesting for me on Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m, Windows 10.

Comment: Well, it seems to work for me (Firefox 47.0.1 on Windows 7). Can't send you a screenshot right now but I can clearly see the "Element" word rendered on the DOM while the alert is shown.

Comment: Yep works for me too in Firefox 47.0.1, behavior has been observed on Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m.

Comment: Same Issue I am facing too. Someone can help that how can use or fixed it for Chrome Browser?  here is the example http://narendra-pal-singh.github.io/Web-Development/html/divBox.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It changes the style synchronously, and you will notice that if you [read back the value on the next line and show it](https://jsfiddle.net/4rsje4b6/2/).

```
$("#test").css("display", "inline");
alert("Showed element!" + $("#test").css("display"));
```

But the change of the style object triggers a repaint request message to the page renderer, and that is handled as soon as the browser becomes idle, which is after this script routine has ended.

It depends on the browser, though. In Edge it works fine, and the element is shown right away but in Chrome and Vivaldi it is not.

Another test to see how browsers handle this: 
If you resize the browser window, JSFiddle will scale (each of the areas keeps the same relative size). If you resize the Vivaldi browser with the alert open, it doesn't do that. In fact if you make it small, then show the alert, then make it larger, you just get a grey area in the new space until you close the message box. In Edge, the fiddle will just resize in the background, even though the entire browser window is grayed out, so it's not just a matter of the time of processing, but more that Chrome completely freezes the page when an alert is open.

Comment: (+1) In other words, in some browsers, the relationship between an object's style-state and its appearance on the screen have a relationship that is updated asynchronously, regardless of the how the style is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This sucks. But I suppose alert dialogs are not used anymore so...

Comment: @apsillers Indeed. Another test. -edit- moved from comment to answer

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia - if you want to guarantee a repaint before some JS put that JS in a timeout callback function [eg. like this](https://jsfiddle.net/4rsje4b6/5/)