# Chrome - Javascript execution sequence problem with alert()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

today I wondered about the execution sequence in Chrome for the JavaScript-function "alert()"

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">
test1 test1 test1 test1 
</div>

<div id="test2">
test2 test2 test2 test2 
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="runTest()" value="start test">

<script>

function runTest()
{
  $('#test1').css('background-color', 'red');
  alert('test1');

  $('#test2').css('background-color', 'red');
 alert('test2');
}

</script>
```

In Firefox 62 and IE11 (works like expected):

```
1) BGcolor Line 1  
2) Alertbox 1  
3) (click OK)  
4) BGcolor Line 2  
5) Alertbox 2  
6) (click OK)
```

In Chrome 69.0.3497.100:

```
1) Alertbox 1  
2) (click OK)   
3) Alertbox 2
4) (click OK)  
5) BGcolor Line 1  
6) BGcolor Line 2
```

Why isn't Chrome fire up the alert() and waiting for click-on-OK?

Thank you
Olli

Comment: Works fine for me in Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is element not being shown before alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960101/why-is-element-not-being-shown-before-alert)

Comment: see particularly the comments on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that an `alert()` is rendered by the browser software, not by the JavaScript runtime or CSS rendering engine and often the browser can work faster/slower than the JavaScript runtime can.  In this case, the `alert` is being rendered before the JavaScript runtime and CSS rendering engine can get the background color to change. And since an `alert()` is a modal dialog, the rest of the UI is blocked until the `alert()` is closed, so you don't see any red background until then.

The solution to this issue is to manually take control of the `alert()` rendering by deferring it until after the current function has completed with a timer:

```js
function runTest() {
    $('#test1').css('background-color', 'red');
    // Timer callback functions are placed in the event queue and
    // won't run until the JavaScript call stack is idle. So,
    // makeAlert("test1") won't run until after runTest(), which
    // will allow the browser to color the background red before
    // the first alert is rendered.
    setTimeout(function(){
      makeAlert("test1");
    }, 100);
}

function makeAlert(msg){
    // Now, the first background has been applied and so
    // we can ask for the first alert().
    alert(msg);
      
    // Now, we'll set the second background color
    $('#test2').css('background-color', 'red');
    
    // And defer the second alert until after this function
    // is complete.
    setTimeout(function(){
      alert("test2");
    }, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">test1 test1 test1 test1</div>
<div id="test2">test2 test2 test2 test2</div>

<input type="button" onclick="runTest()" value="start test">
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing a little bit of research for similar issues, [the answer for this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960101/why-is-element-not-being-shown-before-alert) seems to get it right:

> ... the change of the style object triggers a repaint request message to the page renderer, and that is handled as soon as the browser becomes idle, which is after this script routine has ended.

Only Chrome does this, apparently.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function runTest() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var a = document.querySelector('#test1');
    a.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    alert('test1');
  }, 100);

  setTimeout(function() {
    var a = document.querySelector('#test2');
    a.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    alert('test2');
  }, 200);
  }
```

```html
    <div id="test1">
        test1 test1 test1 test1
    </div>

    <div id="test2">
        test2 test2 test2 test2
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="runTest()" value="start test">
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't contain any explanation or comments as to what the problem is and how your code solves it. Also, it is essentially the same and the accepted answer, which was posted nearly 15 minutes before yours.