# jQuery::addClass() behaves asynchronously? doesn't happen immediately and is blocked by confirm()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `jQuery::addClass()` to add a class to a row when clicking a button, and immediately open a JS `confirm()` dialog.
It seems as if `addClass()` was executing asynchronously as the class change is not reflected until the dialog is closed.
As `addClass()` doesn't have a callback parameter, I can't avoid this unless I call the `confirm` on a timeout, but I don't think that's reliable and may behave differently on different clients.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwyubmvp/)

*Confirm opened, class change still not showing:*
[image]

*When the confirm is closed, the class change shows:*
[image]

*Code:*

```
$("a.delete-email").click( function(event) {
    $(this).parents(".email-result").addClass("confirm-delete");
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this email?'")) {
        // [...]
```

Comment: Please create an [mcve]....

Comment: Try wrapping the `if(confirm...)` in `setTimeout()` to give browser a chance to repaint before the whole UI is blocked by the `confirm()`

Comment: You can set some timeout or use async

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960101/why-is-element-not-being-shown-before-alert